# C++ Array Intersection

Tags: c++, stl, hashtable, intersection

Does anyone know if it's possible to turn this from O(m * n) to O(m + n)?

```
    vector<int> theFirst;
    vector<int> theSecond;
    vector<int> theMatch;

    theFirst.push_back( -2147483648 );
    theFirst.push_back(2);
    theFirst.push_back(44);
    theFirst.push_back(1);
    theFirst.push_back(22);
    theFirst.push_back(1);

    theSecond.push_back(1);
    theSecond.push_back( -2147483648 );
    theSecond.push_back(3);
    theSecond.push_back(44);
    theSecond.push_back(32);
    theSecond.push_back(1);

    for( int i = 0; i < theFirst.size(); i++ )
    {
        for( int x = 0; x < theSecond.size(); x++ )
        {
            if( theFirst[i] == theSecond[x] )
            {
                theMatch.push_back( theFirst[i] );
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?  A little more text would be helpful, as well as what you expect as output in your example.

Comment: Array intersection, same number exists in array a and b. Can be negative or positive numbers. Array a holds m elements and array b holds n elements. Unsorted because sorting factors into performance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the contents of the first vector into a hash set, such as `std::unordered_set`. That is O(m). Scan the second vector, checking if the values are in the unordered_set and keeping a tally of those that are. That is n lookups of a hash structure, so O(n). So, O(m+n). If you have l elements in the overlap, you may count O(l) for adding them to the third vector. `std::unordered_set` is in the C++0x draft and available in the latest gcc versions, and there is also an implementation in [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/boost/unordered_set.html).

**Edited** to use unordered_set

Using C++2011 syntax:

```
unordered_set<int> firstMap(theFirst.begin(), theFirst.end());

for (const int& i : theSecond) {
   if (firstMap.find(i)!=firstMap.end()) {
     cout << "Duplicate: " << i << endl;
     theMatch.push_back(i);
   }
}
```

Now, the question still remains, what do you want to do with duplicates in the originals? Explicitly, how many times should `1` be in `theMatch`, 1, 2 or 4 times?
This outputs:

```
Duplicate: 1
Duplicate: -2147483648
Duplicate: 44
Duplicate: 1
```

Comment: in theMatch dupes are fine, that's another optimization for later.

Comment: and btw, what does const int& i : in a for loop do?

Comment: Well, const int& i is getting the value of each element of the vector by const reference. In this case, since an int is small, it isn't really necessary, you could get it by value `for (int i : theSecond) ...` but if your vector was holding larger objects that are expensive to copy you want const reference.

Comment: is the : from a different language? it is not recognized by my compiler VS2010. although i can make a work around it

Comment: It is C++2011 draft, which I'm not sure how to access from VS2010. It is just a simple loop over the vector, for (vector<int>::const_iterator i=theSecond.begin() ; ...` and so on.

Comment: Well, it is O(m) or O(n), depending which one is larger. Basically O(the largest one) because constants are ignored. I'll put some more useful references up later.

Comment: I added some references in my answer to your other question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6204982/unordered-set-questions/6212106#6212106

Answer (score 2):

Using this: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_intersection/

You should be able to achieve `O(mlogm + nlogn)` I believe. (`set_intersection` requires that the input ranges be already sorted).
This might perform a bit differently than your solution for duplicate elements, however.

Comment: Yes, it's because you have to sort them first. Also, I'm not following exactly what you mean by max number of elements. mlogm + nlogm is asymtotically better than m*n.

Comment: Ahh ok, let's factor in the time to sort the arrays, still better?

Comment: Yes, excluding the sorting factor, it's approx. O(m+n). From the documentation: `At most, performs 2*(count1+count2)-1 comparisons or applications of comp (where countX is the distance between firstX and lastX).`.

Comment: That is nearly perfect but the only issue that I see is having to sort both arrays before because using the .sort function will preform O(n^2) at its worst. Which could be for both arrays. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/

Comment: Then use a merge sort so you have guaranteed worst case O(nlogn). Also, the O(n^2) sort is extremely unlikely - it's the worst case of quicksort, but in most cases, quicksort ends up being faster than merge sort.

Comment: But OP is asking whether it is possible in O(M+N), not O(MlogM+NlogN).

Comment: @Christopher, `std::sort` will give you O(NlogN) on average. You would be very unlucky to reach N^2.

Comment: @jaunchopanza I'm suggesting a solution which is better than the one provided. I'm still providing useful information to OP.

Comment: @Christopher Peterson:  The Standard (in 25.3.1) says that `sort` is approximately O(n log n) on the average, but `stable_sort` is O(n log n) if sufficient memory is available, otherwise O(n (log n)^2), and `partial_sort` is O(n log n) (and you can certainly use `partial_sort` on the whole array by specifying that sorted part will be the whole array).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to produce `theMatch` from two data sets, and you don't care about the data sets themselves, put one in an `unordered_map` (available currently from Boost and listed in the final committee draft for C++11), mapping the key to an integer that increases whenever added to, and therefore keeps track of the number of times the key occurs.  Then, when you get a hit on the other data set, you `push_back` the hit the number of times it occurred in the first time.

You can get to O(n log n + m log m) by sorting the vectors first, or O(n log n + m) by creating a `std::map` of one of them.

Caveat:  these are not order-preserving operations, and `theMatch` will come out in different orders with different techniques.  It looks to me like the order is likely considered arbitrary.  If the order given in the code above is necessary, I don't think there's a better algorithm.

Edit:

Take data set A and data set B, of type Type.  Create an `unordered_map<Type, int>`.

Go through data set A, and check each member to see if it's in the map.  If not, add the element with the `int` 1 to the map.  If it is, increment the `int`.  Each of these operations is O(1) on the average, so this step is O(len A).

Go through data set B, and check each member to see if it's in the map.  If not, go on to the next.  If so, `push_back` the member onto the destination queue.  The `int` is the number of times that value is in data set A, so do the `push_back` the number of times the member's in A to duplicate the behavior given.  Each of these operations is on the average O(1), so this step is O(len B).

This is average behavior.  If you always hit the worst case, you're back with O(m*n).  I don't think there's a way to guarantee O(m + n).

Comment: You might be able to get `O(n log n + m)` if you're using an `unordered_map`, but `std::map` has `log n` insertion and `log n` lookup, so you'd get `O(n log n + m log n)`.

Comment: @Jamie Wong:  In the draft I've got for C++0x, `unordered` has average insertion and retrieval times of O(1).  Build the `unordered_map` (O(n)), read through the other data set, looking it up in the `unordered_map` (O(m)), and you're there.

Comment: may I see an example of what you mean david?

Comment: @Jamie, @Christopher, it is O(n) for n insertions into a hash-something, and O(m) for m lookups into that hash-something structure. Plus O(l) for l push_backs into the overlap vector. See my solution, using `std::unordered_set`.

Comment: @Christopher Peterson Sorry, it would be O(n + m) with `unordered_map`, you're right. My second point should still stand though - `std::map` is is `log n` for insertion and lookup.

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if I am wrong, 
you are suggesting following solution for the intersection problem:
sort two vectors, and keep iteration in both sorted vector in such a way that we reach to a common element,
so overall complexity will be
(n*log(n) + m*log(m)) + (n + m)
Assuming k*log(k) as complexity of sorting

Am I right? 
Ofcourse the complexity will depend on the complexity of sorting.

Comment: They don't need to be sorted, if there is a way without sorting them that could be much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I would sort the longer array O(n*log (n)), search for elements from the shorter array O(m*log (n)). Total is then O(n*log(n) + m*log (n) )

Answer (score -1):

If the order of the elements in the resulting array/set doesn't matter then the answer is yes.

For the arbitrary types of elements with some order defined the best algorithm is `O( max(m,n)*log(min(m,n)) )`. For the numbers of limited size the best algorithm is `O(m+n)`.

- Construct the set of elements of smaller array - for arbitrary elements just sorting is OK and for the numbers of limited size it must be something similar to intermediate table in numeric sort.
- Iterate through larger array and check if the element is within a set constructed earlier - for the arbitrary element binary search is OK (which is `O(log(min(n,m))`) and for numbers the single check is O(1).

Comment: Concatenating the arrays then sorting and removing duplicates gives you the union, not the intersection. And how would limiting the size give you `O(m+n)`? It might give you `O(max(range of m, range of n))`

Comment: I still don't follow how you're getting O(s) for limited size. If you're suggesting hashing/bucketing, then it isn't the size of m and n that's relevant, it's the size of input values themselves (which is invariant of the size of m and n). By hashing each value then running through the hash table, you could get `O(max(range of m, range of n) + m + n)` (my previous comment was wrong). Since the OP seems to be dealing with the full integer range, that would deal with 4 billion ops.

Comment: @Jamie Wong: Will answer later in more details (no time now). But the principle is similar to [radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort).

Comment: @Serge Dundich:  Radix sort only works when you can allocate identifiable buckets for each value of the key, or each value of the key component.  In this case, there seems to be no limit on possible values.

Comment: @Serge Also, radix sort, even on bounded values, isn't O(n) - it's O(kn), where k is the number of digits (varying by what radix you're using).

Comment: @Jamie Wong: So. `O(k*n) = O(sizeof(int)*n) = O(n)`. We can create a hierarchy of tables (e.g. 256 entries each, or 16 entries if we partition integer into 4-bit digits) in linear time `O(min(m,n))`. And then to check if number is within the set we need up to `number_of_int_digits` table lookups (e.g. number_of_int_digits = sizeof(int) if we use bytes as digits), i.e. O(1).